# Como puedo hacer varias peticiones consecutivas si la anterior no me dio resultados en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, promesas

```
var appServices = angular.module('miClaroServices',[]);

appServices.factory('productoServicio', ['$http', '$q',
function($http, $q) {
    // interface
    var service = {
        ListProducto: [],
        getListProductos: getListProductos
    };
    return service;

    // implementation
    function getListProductos() {
        var def = $q.defer();

        $http.get('http://172.19.74.235:8909/ProductoServiciosResulFull/service/obtenerServicios/p')
            .success(function(data) {
                service.ListProducto = data;
                def.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function() {
                def.reject('Failed to get ListProducto');
            });
        return def.promise;
    }
}]);
```

Este es mi controller

```
var appController = angular.module('miClaroController',[]);

    appController.controller('miClaroCtr', ['$scope', 'productoServicio',
    function($scope, productoServicio) {
        var text;
        var vm = $scope;
        vm.ListProducto = [];


        vm.getListProductos = function() {
            productoServicio.getListProductos()
                .then(function(ListProducto) {
                    vm.ListProducto = ListProducto;
                    console.log('Servicio returned to controller.' );
                    console.log(ListProducto);
                },
                function(data) {
                    vm.text = ("Error al consultar los clientes consumer");
                    console.log(text);
                });
        };

        vm.getListProductos();
    }
]);
```

Lo que necesito es que desde el services, si `$http.get` no trae nada, seguir y consultar otro y así hasta 4 JSON hasta que en alguno haya data o no.
Por favor podrían ayudarme ya que soy nuevo en Angular

Answer (score 2):

Esto es algo que tiene que ver con las promesas simplemente encadénalas y tendrás todos los resultados que esperas.

```
service.metodo1().then(function(resultado1) {
    return servicio.metodo2();
}).then(function(resultado2) {
    return servicio.metodo3();
}).then(function(resultado3) {
    return servicio.metodo4();
}).then(function(resultado4) {
    // fin de la cadena
}).catch(function() {
    // en caso que alguno falle se pasa al catch
});
```

En caso que quieras continuar si el server te envía una respuesta vacía aunque no sea un error puedes usar lo siguiente

```
service.metodoX().then(function(resultado) {
    if (!resultado.data) {
        // también puede ser if (!resultado.data.lenght) en caso que sea un arreglo
        return servicio.siguienteMetodo();
    }

    // Si no devuelve nada el resultado de la siguente promesa será undefined
})
// ......
// idem a lo anterior
```

Antes que nada debo decirte que no debes estructurar tus servicios como lo muestras. Usar

```
var def = $q.defer();
//....
return def.promise;
```

Es usualmente un [antipatrón](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern). Si estás intentando cachear los resultados hay un [servicio](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) para eso.

Tu servicio debería quedar así

```
var appServices = angular.module('miClaroServices',[]);

appServices.factory('productoServicio', ['$http', '$q',
function($http, $q) {
    var service = {
        getListProductos: getListProductos
    };
    return service;

    function getListProductos() {
        // Retorna directamente la promesa para manejarla en el controller
        return $http.get('http://172.19.74.235:8909/ProductoServiciosResulFull/service/obtenerServicios/p');
    }
}]);
```

Y tu controller

```
var appController = angular.module('miClaroController',[]);

appController.controller('miClaroCtr', ['$scope', 'productoServicio',
function($scope, productoServicio) {
    var text;
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.ListProducto = [];


    vm.getListProductos = function() {
        productoServicio.getListProductos()
            .then(function(ListProducto) {
                if (!ListProducto) {
                    vm.ListProducto = ListProducto;
                    return productoServicio.getOtraCosa();
                }
            })
            .then(function(otraCosa) {
                // Si la promesa anterior me retornó algo otraCosa es undefined y no entra en el if
                // En caso que sea una cadena vacia llamo al siguiente paso
                if (otraCosa === '') {
                    // o tambien if (!vm.ListProducto)
                    vm.ListProducto = otraCosa;
                    return productoServicio.getDeNuevo();
                }
            })
            .then(function(deNuevo) {
                if (deNuevo === '') {
                    vm.ListProducto = deNuevo;
                }
                // Este es el resultado final por lo que no se encadena más nada
                if (vm.ListProducto) {
                    // Si vm.ListProducto tiene algo es que algún paso me respondió
                }
            }, function(data) {
                // El error es el último ya que no necesitas mas de un manejo de errores en este caso
                vm.text = ("Error al consultar los clientes consumer");
                console.log(text);
            });
    };

    vm.getListProductos();
}
```

]);

Fijate que en mi primer ejemplo yo usé

```
.then(function).then(function).catch(function)
```

mientras que en el otro use

```
.then(function).then(function, function)
```

Los dos son equivalentes pero me parece que el primero es mucho más legible que el segundo por lo que muchas veces la segunda forma es considerada también un [antipatrón](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-.then).

Comment: @jose.luis.lopez Es esto a lo que te referías en tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

en tu servicio, bastaría con hacer lo siguiente:

```
var appServices = angular.module('miClaroServices',[]);

appServices.factory('productoServicio', ['$http', '$q',
function($http, $q) {
    // interface
    var attempts = 0, service = {
        ListProducto: [],
        getListProductos: getListProductos
    };

    return service;

    // implementation
    function getListProductos() {
        var def = $q.defer();

        $http.get('http://172.19.74.235:8909/ProductoServiciosResulFull/service/obtenerServicios/p')
            .success(function(data) {
                if (!data || data.length == 0) {
                    attempts ++;

                    if (attempts <= 4) {
                        getListProductos();
                    } else {
                        def.reject('Failed to get ListProducto');
                        attempts = 0; // Reinicias en el servicio para proximas recuperaciones
                    }
                } else {
                    service.ListProducto = data;

                    def.resolve(data);
                }
            })
            .error(function() {
                def.reject('Failed to get ListProducto');
            });
        return def.promise;
    }
}]);
```

le agregas una variable `attemps` que es simplemente un contador de los intentos de recuperacion. Verificas si los intentos que llevas son menos que 4, entonces intentas volver a recuperar, en caso de que no, haces un `reject` indicando que fallaron tus intentos.